# how to pause setInterval and resume if there is new data from database?

Tags: django, ajax, chart.js

How to pause setInterval if all data from the database are loaded and resumes if there is new data from the database without manual page refresh? The problem with this if I will not use clearinterval(), it will keep on fetching the data repeatedly and will populate the chart with the same data.

```
<script>

  const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
  const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: 'bar',
      data: {
          labels: [],
          datasets: [{
              label: '# of Votes',
              data: [],
              backgroundColor: [
                  'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                  'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                  'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                  'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                  'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                  'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
              ],
              borderColor: [
                  'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                  'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                  'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                  'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                  'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                  'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
              ],
              borderWidth: 1
          }]
      },
      options: {
          scales: {
              y: {
                  beginAtZero: true
              }
          }
      }
  });

  $(document).ready(function(){
    var timer = setInterval(function(){
      var postt = $.ajax({
        type:'GET',
        url: "{% url 'post' %}",
        success: function(response){

          console.log(response.post)
          var count = 0;
          var total = response.post.length
          
          for(var key in response.post)
          {
              myChart.data.labels.push(response.post[key].date);
              myChart.data.datasets.forEach((dataset) => {
              dataset.data.push(response.post[key].number);
              myChart.update();
            });
            
            count++;
            //}
            console.log( myChart.data.labels.length)
            

          }
          console.log(count)
          if(count == total){    // <--- stops the setInterval after all data are loaded.
            clearInterval(timer)
            
          }
          

        },
        error: function(response){
          alert("Error")
        }
      })
      //console.log(postt)
    },1000);
    
  });

  
</script>
```

The code works if I manually refresh the page but I want it to be in real-time. thanks

Comment: cosnider using django-channels, to push the realtime data and invoke javascript. A quick google search on "django channels websocket javascript" will land you in dedicated resources.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but I want to implement this using ajax for practice purposes only.

Comment: there is no way for the javascript which is in client side to know whats happening at the backend, you have to either explicitly make a call from js or use sockets.. sorry but thats how web was designed and why sockets came into play